# Angular 4 observables - scope

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function where i want to set a member to a certain value returned from a http service.

```
calculateDistance() {
for (var ix=0; ix<this.rps.length; ix++) {
  this.googleService._distanceBetween(this.myLatLng, this.rps[ix].latLng)
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.resp = <GeoResponse>response;
    this.rps[ix].distFromMe = this.resp.distance.toString();
  });
}
```

}

The problem is that i don't have access to the array named rps inside the observable.

Is it possible to solve this another way ?

Comment: You should have access, that's the point of arrow functions. Please give a [mcve] including the expected and actual outputs.

Comment: As Jon said, you should have access. What makes you think you don't? Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Comment: I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'distFromMe' of undefined" when i try to set it. If i print the array when i'm outside the observable/subscribe it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused as you have declared the forLoop index 'ix' using 'var'. As its 'var' the scope is retained and value of 'ix' will be (this.rps.length + 1) when the call back to subscribe is done. i.e, if array length is 5, value of ix will be 6 when the call back happens. Hence you get the error as this.rps[ix] is undefined. Modify the forLoop as below:

```
for (var ix=0; ix<this.rps.length; ix++) {
//create an inner function to maintain the closure for ix;
  ((index: number) => {
  this.googleService._distanceBetween(this.myLatLng, this.rps[index].latLng)
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.resp = <GeoResponse>response;
    this.rps[index].distFromMe = this.resp.distance.toString();
  });
  })(ix); // calls the created function
}
```